# Why I can't use operator+ with reverse_iterator?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I have this code:

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
...
void f() {
    std::set<std::pair<int, std::string>> orderByRating;
    /*...*/
    for (auto revIter = orderByRating.rbegin(); revIter != orderByRating.rend(); revIter++) {
        int subsetSz = 1;
        auto curIter = revIter + subsetSz;
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

and I have this compile error

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\xutility(1374): error C2784: 'unknown-type std::operator -(const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::pair<int,std::string>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\xutility(2278): note: see declaration of 'std::operator -'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\xutility(1373): note: while compiling class template member function 'std::reverse_iterator<std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>> std::reverse_iterator<std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>>::operator +(int) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::pair<int,std::string>
1>        ]
1>c:\users\user\source\repos\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(57): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::reverse_iterator<std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>> std::reverse_iterator<std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>>::operator +(int) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::pair<int,std::string>
1>        ]
1>c:\users\user\source\repos\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(53): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::reverse_iterator<std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::pair<int,std::string>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\xutility(1374): error C2784: 'unknown-type std::operator -(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::pair<int,std::string>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\xutility(1413): note: see declaration of 'std::operator -'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\xutility(1374): error C2676: binary '-': 'const std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::pair<int,std::string>
1>        ]
```

Can you help me to understand what's wrong and how to do it right?

I want to make a subset from current reverse_iterator position and then to sort it by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator+` can only be used on [random access iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator). `std::set::iterator` is a [bidirectional iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator), and so is a reverse iterator obtained from it, because a [reverse iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) has the same iterator category.

To advance a bidirectional iterator by `n` elements, you can use [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next):

```
auto curIter = std::next(revIter, subsetSz);
```

Note that for random access iterators, `iter + n` is `O(1)` operation, whereas for bidirectional ones, `std::next(iter, n)` is `O(n)`.